# how to redirect output of command line execution to more than one file according to weight of output

Tags: linux, pipe, awk

Currently I'm using an awk line to filter a set of files according to certain criteria.

How can I redirect the result output to more than one file if the result, for example if the file that would be generated is larger than 1 Mb or has more than N lines? I want to name my results result_1.txt, result_2.txt, etc.

p.s: I want to split my result in files of 1Mb or N lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output to `split`

`man split`